# Random Number Generation within a Matrix C Programming

Tags: random

I'm trying to design a program which outputs a grid of random 0 and 1's, so each position in the grid is equally as likely to have a 1 rather than a 0. I have managed to get the grid sorted with variable sizes but I cant think of a way to randomly assign each position a number. All I have done is assign all positions to 0 so far.

```
int Lx,Ly,x,y;

printf("Input height\n");
scanf("%d", &Lx);
printf("Input width\n");
scanf("%d", &Ly);

char mat[Lx][Ly];

for(x=0;x<Lx;x++)
for(y=0;y<Ly;y++)
mat[Lx][Ly]='0';

for(x=0;x<Lx;x++)
{
     for(y=0;y<Ly;y++)
    printf("%c\t",mat[Lx][Ly]);
    putchar('\n');
}
return(0);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use `rand() % 2`:

```
char mat[Lx][Ly];

for (x=0; x < Lx; x++)
{
    for (y=0; y < Ly; y++)
    {
        int i = rand() % 2;   // 0 or 1 as int
        char cell = '0' + i;  // 0 or 1 as ASCII character
        mat[x][y] = cell;     // store character in matrix
    }
}
```

Printing

```
for(x=0; x < Lx; x++)
{
    for (y=0; y < Ly; y++)
        printf("%c\t",mat[x][y]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I can see how this would work, however when I implement it into my program I seem to now only get space as an output and not numbers

Comment: Ah ok it is now printing correctly. However if i enter different grid sizes there is a random change to it, but if i enter say 4x4 grid multiple times it is always the same output

Comment: What size grid do you need?  Assuming a fixed grid size and fixed seed number, my code should always give you the same reproducible layout.

Comment: Well the idea is to input the grid size, but the grid should be random, such that if i run the program twice at the same grid size the grid should be different, but it outputs the same currently and im not sure how to alter that, thanks again

Comment: Ah i think i have solved it, I didnt add a separate seed, ive just added srand ( time(NULL) ); outside the for loop and it seems to be working now

Comment: Please mark correct if it solved your problem thanks.

Answer (score 0):

mat[Lx][Ly]=x;
where x is the rest of the random function divided by 2

Answer (score 0):

Within the for loop just assign the elements like:

```
for(x=0;x<Lx;x++)
{
    for(y=0;j<Ly;y++)
    {
    mat[x][y]=rand()%2;
    }
}
```

use this and all the elements will be either 0 or 1 because it generates mod 2 values which will be 0 or 1.